# Listen to synchronous callbacks with C#

Tags: c#, callback, synchronous

I have a program which write data to a USB HID device. When data is received from the USB device I get a callback from the `usblib` library through a delegate event `DataRecievedEventHandler`.

I am used to programming on firmware with interrupts, so that I can do

```
while(!flag); // Will continue when interrupt triggers and change the flag
```

I want to write an array element by element to the USB and wait for a return from the device after each array element

```
for (int i = 0; i > 16; i++)
{ 
    sendUsbData(array[i]);
    while(!receivedComplete);
    // Wait for response from USB before transmitting next iteration
}
```

The problem is that the callback will not get triggered when I'm spooling in that `while` loop. Any suggestion on how to do these kind of operations?

The library I am using for USB communication is the same as [this one](https://github.com/djpnewton/beaverbot/tree/master/diagnostic/cs_usb_hid/usb%20hid/UsbLibrary). In *SpecifiedDevice.cs* there is a method called `public void SendData(byte[] data)` which I am using to send arrays of bytes.

Transmit method:

```
public void sendUsbData(byte _txData)
{
    byte[] txData = new byte[this.usb.SpecifiedDevice.OutputReportLength];
    txData[1] = 0x50; // 0x50 = loopback command. Element 0 is always 0x00

    int pos = 2;
    foreach (byte b in _flashData)
    {
        txData[pos] = b;
        pos++;
    }

        this.usb.SpecifiedDevice.SendData(txData);
}
```

Upon received data from USB, the callback `usb_OnDataRecieved` is called.

```
private void usb_OnDataRecieved(object sender, DataRecievedEventArgs args)
{
    this.ParseReceivePacket(args.data); // Format to string and print to textbox
    /*public bool*/receiveComplete = true; 
}
```

Comment: Can you present the actual code within `sendUsbData` and the code that updates `receivedFlagRaised`?

Comment: Do you ever get a callback? Plus: `receivedFlagRaised` is not `receiveComplete`.

Comment: @meilke I changed the naming, forgot to update here. The dongle I communicate with loops the data back, and I get the callback. Some hickups is occuring because I send data to fast, but I almost get all data back in return (due to the command byte I am giving the dongle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch to using a `AutoResetEvent` wait handle:

```
public void sendUsbData(byte _txData)
{
  byte[] txData = new byte[this.usb.SpecifiedDevice.OutputReportLength];
  txData[1] = 0x50; // 0x50 = loopback command. Element 0 is always 0x00

  int pos = 2;
  foreach (byte b in _flashData)
  {
    txData[pos] = b;
    pos++;
  }

  // reset member wait handle
  waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false); 
  this.usb.SpecifiedDevice.SendData(txData);
}

private void usb_OnDataRecieved(object sender, DataRecievedEventArgs args)
{
  this.ParseReceivePacket(args.data); // Format to string and print to textbox

  // signal member wait handle
  waitHandle.Set();
}
```

And then in your for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i > 16; i++)
{ 
  sendUsbData(array[i]);

  // wait for member wait handle to be set
  waitHandle.WaitOne();
}
```

Comment: Am I able to access `waitHandle` when it is instantiated like that within the method?

Comment: You need to define a member.

Comment: And that is where you lost me :P

Comment: Like the bool flag you had before. The wait handle takes its place.

Comment: No. I understand that your USB library is communicating asynchronously by itself and is notifying you by creating events. And you want to block your code as long as one communication is going on. You need to make it synchronous again. Hence the `AutoResetEvent`.

Comment: It is stuck at `WaitOne`, it never gets to the callback.

Comment: I started the send method in a new thread, think I got it to work. Will test more tomorrow. Thank you.